# Page Refresh does not re-populate DropDownList from previous selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML website that when selecting a value in one DropDownList, populates a second list depending on your selection. When refreshing the page, or hitting back from a redirected page, the first DropDownList is still the value you first selected, but the second DropDownList will not be populated. Fixes?

You can view the issue I am describing at GiveToTheYToday.org if you so wish.

```
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function populate(br,ca){
            var br = document.getElementById(br);
            var ca = document.getElementById(ca);
            ca.innerHTML = "";
            if(br.value == "ASO"){
                var optionArray = ["|","/aso/barbara_lankford.html|Barbara Lankford",
                "/aso/howard_holloman.html|Howard Holloman","/aso/tricia_burke.html|Tricia Burke"]
             } 
             else if(br.value == "Bullitt County"){
                var optionArray = ["|","home.html|"]
            } 
             else if(br.value == "Chestnut Street"){
                var optionArray = ["|","home.html|"]
            } 
             else if(br.value == "Clark County"){
                var optionArray = ["|", "/clark/colita_moore.html|Colita Moore",
                "/clark/rachel_hollensead.html|Rachel Hollensead"]
            } 
             else if(br.value == "Downtown"){
                var optionArray = ["|","/downtown/debbie_eberenz.html|Debbire Eberenz",
                "/downtown/gaylee_gillim.html|Gaylee Gillim"]
            } 
             else if(br.value == "Floyd County"){
                var optionArray = ["|","/floyd/robyn_beard.html|Robyn Beard",
                "/floyd/shane_thomas.html|Shane Thomas"]
            } 
             else if(br.value == "Northeast"){
                var optionArray = ["|","/northeast/adam_johnson.html|Adam Johnson", "/northeast/amy_mcclain.html|Amy McClain",
                "/northeast/ashley_hopkins.html|Ashley Hopkins", "/northeast/brandon_white.html|Brandon White",
                "/northeast/dale_burnham.html|Dale Burnham",
                "/northeast/dee_fairfield.html|Dee Fairfield", "/northeast/doug_roemer.html|Doug Roemer",
                "/northeast/jack_danehy.html|Jack Danehy", "/northeast/jennifer_broadbridge.html|Jennifer Broadbridge",
                "/northeast/jessica_tretter.html|Jessica Tretter", "/northeast/joey_skidmore.html|Joey Skidmore",
                "/northeast/lindsey_brown.html|Lindsey Brown", "/northeast/lori_fitzgerald.html|Lori Fitzgerald",
                "/northeast/mac_brown.html|Mac Brown",
                "/northeast/megan_schulte.html|Megan Schulte", "/northeast/melanie_vittitow.html|Melanie Vittitow",
                "/northeast/michael_ngong.html|Michael Ngong", "/northeast/morgan_white.html|Morgan White",
                "/northeast/ralph_piercy.html|Ralph Piercy", "/northeast/ron_burse.html|Ron Burse",
                "/northeast/roscelle_griffin.html|Roscelle Griffin","/northeast/rudy_havira.html|Rudy Havira",
                "/northeast/semra_meredith.html|Semra Meredith", "/northeast/sheila_pierce.html|Sheila Pierce",
                "/northeast/stephanie_morgan-white.html|Stephanie Morgan-White", "/northeast/terry_smith.html|Terry Smith",
                "/northeast/valerie_chinn.html|Valerie Chinn"]
             }
             else if(br.value == "Norton Commons"){
                var optionArray = ["|","/norton_commons/allyson_vitato.html|Allyson Vitato",
                "/norton_commons/ashley_porter.html|Ashley Porter"]
            }
             else if(br.value == "Oldham County"){
                var optionArray = ["|","/oldham/kristin_compton.html|Kristin Compton"]
            }
             else if(br.value == "School-Age Child Care"){
                var optionArray = ["|","/sacc/brandon_yates.html|Brandon Yates"]
            }
             else if(br.value == "Southeast"){
                var optionArray = ["|","/southeast/chuck_jackson.html|Chuck Jackson", "/southeast/crysten_minzenberger.html|Crysten Minzenberger",
                "/southeast/john_odom.html|John Odom","/southeast/john_oliva.html|John Oliva",
                "/southeast/kristina_kluesner.html|Kristina Kluesner","/southeast/lakesha_washington.html|LaKesha Washington",
                "/southeast/steve_sexton.html|Steve Sexton"]
            }
             else if(br.value == "Southwest"){
                var optionArray = ["|", "/southwest/ashtyn_begley.html|Ashtyn Begley",
                "/southwest/deonna_tinsley.html|Deonna Tinsley",
                "/southwest/joseph_tindle.html|Joseph Tindle",
                "/southwest/jenifer_roberts.html|Jenifer Roberts"]
            }
            for(var option in optionArray){
               var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
               var newOption = document.createElement("option");
               newOption.value = pair[0];
               newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
               ca.options.add(newOption);
            }
        }
    </script><!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<header><img alt="" height="239" src="http://givetotheytoday.org/campaign_files/2016_header.jpg" width="960" /></header>

<div class="sidebar1">
<nav>
<ul>
    <li>
    <div align="center"><img alt="" height="auto" src="http://givetotheytoday.org/campaign_files/general.png" width="300" /></div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://givetotheytoday.org"><img alt="" height="174" src="http://givetotheytoday.org/campaign_files/give_today.png" width="278" /></a></li>
    <li>
    <div align="center"><iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6q1zUyecvt4" style="border: 3px solid #EEE;" width="290"></iframe><!-- end .content --></div>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- end .sidebar1 --></nav>
</div>

<article class="content">
<section>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p>In 2016, <b>over 16,000 people experienced our local YMCA because of the generous support of our compassionate Louisville community.</b> With your support, we can make sure that everyone who needs the Y has the opportunity to learn, grow and thrive.</p>

<p>To navigate to a campaigner, select their appropriate YMCA branch and campaigner name below:</p>

<hr />
<div align="center">
<form>Select a Branch: <select id="Branch" name="Branch" onchange="populate(this.id,'Campaigner')"><option value=""></option><option value="ASO">ASO</option><option value="Bullitt County">Bullitt County</option><option value="Chestnut Street">Chestnut Street</option><option value="Clark County">Clark County</option><option value="Downtown">Downtown</option><option value="Floyd County">Floyd County</option><option value="Northeast">Northeast</option><option value="Norton Commons">Norton Commons</option><option value="Oldham County">Oldham County</option><option value="School-Age Child Care">School-Age Child Care</option><option value="Southeast">Southeast</option><option value="Southwest">Southwest</option> </select><br />
Select a Campaigner: <select id="Campaigner" name="Campaigner" onchange="window.location.href=this.value"></select></form>
```

Comment: I suggest you to remove the problem and clear the selected value every time in document.ready.. Beacuse if u try to refresh, u will se the first select with an element but if you go to the second select u cannot see the right element.

Take a look here : https://snag.gy/qyhT1K.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your function is run only when the script is loaded. When you go back from the browser the script isn't loaded again, since it's already there in your html file.

An easy fix is to "listen" DOM events and execute the function accordingly. Something like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  populate();
});
```

This way your function will be executed each time the DOM is loaded.

More on DOM events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Side note: why you have two arguments in your function (never used)?

**UPDATE**

I looked closer at your code live and it turned out that you always call your function passing 'Branch' as a first parameter and 'Campaigner' as second. So you can call your function as I said before, but you need to pass those two parameters as strings:

```
populate('Branch', 'Campaigner');
```

Comment: This is where i am adding the DOMContentLoaded and it doesn't seem to be working for me.
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
        function populate(br,ca){
            var br = document.getElementById(br);
            var ca = document.getElementById(ca);
            ca.innerHTML = "";
            if(br.value == "ASO"){....

            ...newOption.value = pair[0];
               newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
               ca.options.add(newOption);
            }
        });
    </script>

Comment: I also don't understand why i would be passing 'Branch' and 'Campaigner' as a string?

I have the br value changed depending on each If statement as a string, and using .split I'm desginating the second half as the campaigner name as a string to output into the DropDownList

Comment: (I apologize I am fairly new to Javascript)

Comment: You can't declare a named function in a callback statement. As I wrote before, you need to pass an anonymous function as a callback to `document.addEventListener`, and inside your anonymous function call `populate('Branch','Campaigner')`. I said you need to pass two string because this is how you implemented your function at the moment. Passing the value of the select to populate makes much more sense to me, but this is not how you have implemented your function. You retrieve the value inside the function, here: `var br = document.getElementById(br).value;`